# Loop Adding Calculated Fields to Multiple Pivot Tables

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add two calced fields into 24 pivot tables across 8 worksheets. It it based on choice of a data validation list in B4 on Sheet 1.

The code to remove the current two calced fields is working:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField

On Error Resume Next
If Intersect(Target, Sheet1.Range("B4")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pt In sht.PivotTables
        For Each pf In pt.DataFields
            pf.DataRange.Cells(1, 1).PivotItem.Visible = False
        Next pf
    Next pt
Next sht
```

Next, I need to add two new calculated fields which I can't get to work:

```
If Sheet1.Range("B4") = "Hourly Utilization" Then
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pt In sht.PivotTables
            With pt
                .AddDataField sht.PivotTables( _
                "*").PivotFields("hClientUtil"), "Client"
                .DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "#0.0%"

                .AddDataField sht.PivotTables( _
                "*").PivotFields("hProdUtil"), "Productive"
                .DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "#0.0%"
            End With
        Next pt
    Next sht
End If
```

I can get it working if a specify the pivot table by sheet and name but I'd like to be able to loop it instead of have the code repeated 24 times.

I'm thinking it maybe something with the "*" as I dont know how to specify the pivot table without using the pivot table name. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I only half figured it out...

To give more background, Sheet 1 has 12 pivot tables, Sheets 2-7 each have 1 and sheet 8 has 5. On the sheets with more than 1 pivot table, they are stacked vertically--as an example on sheet 1, PT1 starts in A5, PT2 in A15, PT3 in A25 and so on.

The code pasted below works for all of them except for the last 5 tables on Sheet1. I have Field Headers disabled on all Pivot tables. The weird thing is if I enable field headers on the last 5 tables, the VBA works. It also still works if I enable field headers on any of the other tables.

**My question is why would the code run on some tables with or without field headers but only run on the 5 tables in question with field headers enabled?** Full code is below...

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField

'VBA only runs if cell B4 on the Summary tab is changed

On Error Resume Next
If Intersect(Target, Sheet1.Range("B4")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Removes values from Pivot Tables

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pt In sht.PivotTables
        For Each pf In pt.DataFields
            pf.DataRange.Cells(1, 1).PivotItem.Visible = False
        Next pf
    Next pt
Next sht

'When Hourly Utilization is chosen

If Sheet1.Range("B4") = "Hourly Utilization" Then
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pt In sht.PivotTables
            With sht.PivotTables(pt.Name)
                .AddDataField sht.PivotTables( _
                pt.Name).PivotFields("hClientUtil"), "Client"
                .AddDataField sht.PivotTables( _
                pt.Name).PivotFields("hProdUtil"), "Prod."
                .DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "#0.0%"
            End With
        Next pt
    Next sht
End If

'When $ Weighted Utilization is chosen

If Sheet1.Range("B4") = "$ Weighted Utilization" Then
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pt In sht.PivotTables
            With sht.PivotTables(pt.Name)
                .AddDataField sht.PivotTables( _
                 pt.Name).PivotFields("dClientUtil"), "Client"
                .AddDataField sht.PivotTables( _
                 pt.Name).PivotFields("dProdUtil"), "Prod."
                .DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "#0.0%"
            End With
        Next pt
    Next sht
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I realized that the 5 pivot tables that the code is not working on is because they only have one row of values so the `pf.DataRange.Cells(1, 1).PivotItem.Visible = False` selects the cell under the row of values. However, if I change the reference to Cells(0,1) to select the upper most left cell in the Data Range, the code filters out the first week of data (I have weeks running across the columns).